# Puppeteer - Login falied only at automation

Tags: authentication, automation, puppeteer

I'm trying to do login at a web page but when I try to do it through Puppeteer it fails.

The code below should redirect with success to https://prenotami.esteri.it/UserArea but it fails and redirect to https://prenotami.esteri.it/Home/Login

```cs
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false, ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--enable-automation']});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://prenotami.esteri.it/UserArea');

  await page.evaluate(() => {
    document.querySelector('#login-email').value = "****@gmail.com"
    document.querySelector('#login-password').value = "pass***"    
    document.querySelector('button[type="submit"]').click()
  })

})();
```

As it can be seen, I've tried to disable automation.I also tried to put some delay but I couldn't realize where exactly

SOLVED:

I've changed the code and it works now

```js
const extra = require('puppeteer-extra');
const stealth = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')
extra.use(stealth())
extra
  .launch({
    headless: false,
    args: ['--no-sandbox']
  })
  .then(async browser => {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://prenotami.esteri.it/');
    page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(30000)
    await page.type("#login-email", "*****@gmail.com") 
    await page.type("#login-password", "*****pass") 
    await page.click('button[type="submit"]')
    await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' })
    await page.goto("https://prenotami.esteri.it/Services/Booking/751") 
    await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' })
```